# Makefile: call multiline variable inside for loop

Tags: makefile

Here's my code:

```
la := a b c d
lb := 1 2 3 4

define test =
    First line $$vara
    Second line $$varb
endef
export test

@for vara in $(la); do \
    for varb in $(lb); do \
        echo $$vara $$varb; \
        echo "$$test"; \
    done \
done
```

Later this output will go in a file I'm creating using `cat`.

I'm expecting something like

```
a 1
First line a
Second line 1
a 2
First line a 
Second line 2
...
```

But instead I'm getting

```
a 1
$vara $varb
a 2 
$vara $varb
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

I used as a base @Beta's answer and changed it a bit to allow it to save the result in a file and send it over SSH to another terminal.

```
define test
[program:$$s-$$c]\nString 1\nString 2\n...\nThe End.
endef
export test

testmake:
    @for s in $(serv); do \
        for c in $(cust); do \
            ssh user@host "mkdir -p /var/log/$$s/$$c"; \
            echo "$(call test)" | ssh user@host "cat > /test.txt"; \
        done \
    done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me in GNU Make 3.81 (but there are some fussy little differences between versions, so you may have to tweak it):

```
define test
  echo First line $$vara; \
  echo Second line $$varb
endef
export test

some_rule:
    @for vara in $(la); do \
      for varb in $(lb); do \
       echo $$vara $$varb; \
       $(call test); \
      done \
     done
```

Note that this has the loops in a recipe -- which is what I inferred you were doing. If you want the loops to run outside a rule, the solution will look quite different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! With a bit of tinkering it worked fine also to store the string inside a file.
I'll edit my answer with my final solution.